# MySQL auto increment copy value in a second column while inserting

Tags: mysql, database

When creating a new line in my database I have a column '`identifier`' which is `primary key auto-increment` and another column which is '`originalIdentifier`' that would requires to take the same value as the auto-incremented '`identifier`' during insertion. The only solution I know is to use the `lastInsertedId` and update the lastly inserted row. Could it be possible to update both column during insertion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the help of trigger (`AFTER INSERT`) to update `originalIdentifier` column with the value of `identifier` after the insert operation.

Comment: thanks! Do you know if one can use a triggers while inserting using PDO in php?

Comment: Part of DDL, with table schema. `CREATE TRIGGER ins_idftable AFTER INSERT FOR EACH ROW SET originalIdentifier = identifier WHERE originalIdentifier IS NULL;`

Comment: Yes, I think so. Because PDO is just a wrapper built but at the end of it, its SQL queries being processed by MySQL. And triggers are also written and triggered by MySQL only. So it would work :-)

Comment: No, you can't do this with an `AFTER INSERT` trigger in MySQL (and neither with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger because then the new auto-incremented value is not available yet.)

Comment: @ypercube okay, well then I'll stick to this two step solution. thanks